# React progressive web app, not loading due to import/export

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still pretty new to react development but I'm trying to create a desktop PWA with a dashboard and sidebar layout

I have my app file and then two components inside components/sidebar/ folders so the structure inside

src/
  app.js

components/
    SidebarComponent.js
    MenuItemComponent.js

I'm running into an error on build though. When I build it says "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `MenuItemComponent`."

I've changed the imports to add '.js' at the end but it didn't work

what am I doint wrong here?

App.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Column, Row } from 'simple-flexbox';
    import { StyleSheet, css } from 'aphrodite';
    import SidebarComponent from './Components/sidebar/SidebarComponent.js';
    import HeaderComponent from './Components/header/HeaderComponent.js';
    import './App.css';

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            height: '100vh'
        },
        content: {
            marginTop: 54
        },
        mainBlock: {
            backgroundColor: '#F7F8FC',
            padding: 30
        }
    });

    class App extends React.Component {

        state = { selectedItem: 'Tickets' };

        render() {
            const { selectedItem } = this.state;
            return (
                <Row className={css(styles.container)}>
                    <SidebarComponent selectedItem={selectedItem} onChange={(selectedItem) => this.setState({ selectedItem })} />
                    <Column flexGrow={1} className={css(styles.mainBlock)}>
                        <HeaderComponent title={selectedItem} />
                        <div className={css(styles.content)}>
                            <span>Content</span>
                        </div>
                    </Column>
                </Row>
            );
        }
    }

    export default App;
```

SidebarComponent.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Column } from 'simple-flexbox';
    import { StyleSheet, css } from 'aphrodite';
    import LogoComponent from './LogoComponent.js';
    import MenuItemComponent from './MenuItemComponent.js';

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            backgroundColor: '#363740',
            width: 255,
            paddingTop: 32
        },
        menuItemList: {
            marginTop: 52
        },
        separator: {
            borderTop: '1px solid #DFE0EB',
            marginTop: 16,
            marginBottom: 16,
            opacity: 0.06
        }
    });

    function SidebarComponent(props) {
        return (
            <Column className={css(styles.container)}>
                <LogoComponent />
                <Column className={css(styles.menuItemList)}>
                    <MenuItemComponent
                        title="Overview" 
                        onClick={() => props.onChange('Overview')}
                        active={props.selectedItem === 'Overview'}
                    />
                    <MenuItemComponent
                        title="Tickets" 
                        onClick={() => props.onChange('Tickets')}
                        active={props.selectedItem === 'Tickets'}
                    />
                    <MenuItemComponent
                        title="Ideas" 
                        onClick={() => props.onChange('Ideas')}
                        active={props.selectedItem === 'Ideas'} />
                    <MenuItemComponent
                        title="Contacts" 
                        onClick={() => props.onChange('Contacts')}
                        active={props.selectedItem === 'Contacts'} />
                    <MenuItemComponent
                        title="Agents" 
                        onClick={() => props.onChange('Agents')}
                        active={props.selectedItem === 'Agents'} />
                    <MenuItemComponent
                        title="Articles" 
                        onClick={() => props.onChange('Articles')}
                        active={props.selectedItem === 'Articles'} />
                    <div className={css(styles.separator)}></div>
                    <MenuItemComponent
                        title="Settings" 
                        onClick={() => props.onChange('Settings')}
                        active={props.selectedItem === 'Settings'} />
                    <MenuItemComponent
                        title="Subscription" 
                        onClick={() => props.onChange('Subscription')}
                        active={props.selectedItem === 'Subscription'} />
                </Column>
            </Column>
        );
    }

    export default SidebarComponent;
```

MenuItemComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { bool, func, string } from 'prop-types';
import { Row } from 'simple-flexbox';
import { StyleSheet, css } from 'aphrodite';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    activeBar: {
        height: 56,
        width: 3,
        backgroundColor: '#DDE2FF',
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0
    },
    activeContainer: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(221,226,255, 0.08)'
    },
    activeTitle: {
        color: '#DDE2FF'
    },
    container: {
        height: 56,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        ':hover': {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(221,226,255, 0.08)'
        },
        paddingLeft: 32,
        paddingRight: 32
    },
    title: {
        fontFamily: 'Muli',
        fontSize: 16,
        lineHeight: '20px',
        letterSpacing: '0.2px',
        color: '#A4A6B3',
        marginLeft: 24
    }
});

function MenuItemComponent(props) {
    const { active, icon, title, ...otherProps } = props;
    const Icon = icon;
    return (
        <Row className={css(styles.container, active && styles.activeContainer)} vertical="center" {...otherProps}>
            {active && <div className={css(styles.activeBar)}></div>}
            <Icon fill={active && "#DDE2FF"} opacity={!active && "0.4"} />
            <span className={css(styles.title, active && styles.activeTitle)}>{title}</span>
        </Row>
    );
}

MenuItemComponent.propTypes = {
    active: bool,
    icon: func,
    title: string
};

export default MenuItemComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show output of 
`console.log(MenuItemComponent)`

if it isn't undefined then replace

```
<Row className={css(styles.container, active && styles.activeContainer)} vertical="center" {...otherProps}>
        {active && <div className={css(styles.activeBar)}></div>}
        <Icon fill={active && "#DDE2FF"} opacity={!active && "0.4"} />
        <span className={css(styles.title, active && styles.activeTitle)}>{title}</span>
    </Row>
```

on

```
<div>Text</div>
```

And build project again

Comment: where do I put the console log statement?

Comment: after import MenuItemComponent. in SidebarComponent.js

Comment: It wasn't undefined. The replacement you gave me has the error InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document'

Comment: if it wasn't undefined then result of render of MenuItemComponent is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Is MenuItemComponent looks like

```
function MenuItemComponent(props) {
        const { active, icon, title, ...otherProps } = props;
        const Icon = icon;
        return (
            <div>Text</div>
        );
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I have